# SSIS Flat File Connection Manager Code Page

Tags: ssis, flat-file, codepages

Trying to create a flat file connection to one of the .txt files.
By default the code page is being selected as 65001(UTF-8).I converted this into Latin 1252(by selecting the code page from the drop down list) and closed the window.When I reopened the connection manager editor,I could see the same 65001(UTF-8)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I ran into similar situation. Open the file in Notepad++ and go to Encoding and hit Convert to UCS-2 Little Endian.

The file that you are trying to import is encoded in UTF-8 and that is why when you open flat file connection manager, it selects 65001 (UTF-8) as code page.

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking on the small "Unicode" checkbox and see if that helps.